# Embed variable as from or to date. Should this work

Tags: low, low-nice-date

EE2.9.2, Low Nice Date 2.2.1

**Main template:**

```
{exp:zoo_visitor:details}
{embed="applications/_author-application-list"
    memberDob="{cf_stual_date_of_birth timezone='Europe/London'}"
    courseStartDateUnix="{exp:low_variables:single var="lv_course_start_ba_mt" format='%U'}"
    minimumAge="{lv_course_min_age_ba_mt}"
    }
{/exp:zoo_visitor:details}
```

{cf_stual_date_of_birth} is a DropDate custom field - Value: 5th March 1998
{lv_course_start_ba_mt} is a Low variable Time Date field - Value: 30th September 2015
{lv_course_min_age_ba_mt} is a Low variable text field - Value: 21

I'm using an embed for other reasons. I've stripped lots of stuff out for this example.

**Embedded Template: applications/_author_application_list**

```
{exp:low_nice_date:range from="{embed:memberDob}" to="{embed:courseStartDateUnix}"}
    <p>{years} / {embed:minimumAge}</p>
    {if "{years}" >= "{embed:minimumAge}"}
        <p>YES</p>
    {if:else}
        <p>NO</p>
    {/if}
{/exp:low_nice_date:range}
```

This returns:

```
<p>17 / 21</p>
<p>YES</p>
```

So it seems like the embed variables are working as the to and from values in the Low Nice Date tag but not in the conditional. Should this work? Is this a parse order issue? Any idea for a workaround?

I have tried using the CC Time Difference add-on as well but I ran into some other issues with that. This is the closest I've got to a working solution.

Answer (score 0):

It was a parse order issue and switching on **Early Parsing** in Low Variables for **{lv_course_min_age_ba_mt}** has fixed it.

Woot!